Why simulation result of BSP129 by PSpice is not the same as in practice?
I want to make a current limiter circuit using the "BSP129" Transistor.
I have made a simulation file using the cadence software and found this component in its Pspice library.
In practice, when I use an 84-ohm resistor, the circuit only draws 22~23mA in the short-circuit state while the simulation results are not even close. Here is the simulation photo:

In the property window of the component I found 4 parameters I think we have to modify:
DC:(Channel Length Modulation Parameter) 
DGFS: (Gate-to-Source Forward Transconductance) 
DRDSON:(Drain-Source On Resistance) 
DVTH:(Threshold Voltage)

as I get help from AI and checked in the datasheet the parameters should be as follow:
DC = as default
DGFS = transconductance: 0.36 S
DRDSON = 4.2
DVTH = -1

Here are the new results:

Will you please tell me guide me to solve my problem?
It is a bit strange if I manually enter these parameters for every component I use.
I don't know whether I entered the correct values.

It looks like the current mismatch you're seeing is likely due to differences between the simulation model and real-world behavior. The BSP129's PSpice model may not perfectly match the practical characteristics, especially regarding RDS(ON) and threshold voltage. I recommend ensuring your VGS is correct since this P-channel MOSFET needs proper gate-source control to conduct. Also, try sourcing an official PSpice model from Infineon and double-check the resistor's actual value with a multimeter to confirm it matches the design.

BSP 129 is an N channel depletion mode FET.
